# Printer about once a month prints a page with the text 'GGG'. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: printer, virus

This occurs randomly and can not be predicted. I have already 3 pages like that collected over the last 3 months.
This happens by itself. The user reads a webpage (no clicks for 2 minutes) and suddenly the printer starts printing blank page with just 1 line of 'GGG' text.

This is at work and it is a network HP laser printer (basic model) (HP LaserJet P4015n).
There is an enterprise print server.  Print jobs (by the user) are submitted to the printer by the print server.

How can I tell if it is my PC or some other network PC ?
How can I examine the printer queue to find out the source of this printing "virus"?

Comment: The answer depends on your setup. Do you have centralized print server, or computers send jobs directly to the printer?

Comment: What printer specifically?

Comment: printer now added and also setup specified.

Comment: If the printer was an old serial one I'd suspect it was some sort of sync sequence.  But that doesn't make sense for any modern printer.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your network security department if they do a vulnerability scan against the printer(s). Some nessus check could be responsible for this!